# Angular 2 и массив

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Доброго времени суток! Делаю небольшой проект на Angular 2. Споткнулся на простой вещи. Есть такой класс (app.data.ts):

```
export class Record {
  public id_gng : number;
  public kod3  :string;
  public deleted : any;
}

export class DataResponse {
  public data : Record[];
}
```

Я заполняю объект DataResponse данными из json в PHP-скрипте. Вот код app.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
class AppService {

    constructor(private http:Http) {

    }

    public get(url:string) {
        return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
    }

    public handleError(error:any) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

Никак не могу перебрать циклом экземпляр DataResponse. Вот код, который не могу заставить работать

```
export class AppComponent {
    public result : DataResponse;

    public setResponse(result:DataResponse) {
        this.result = result;
    }


    constructor(private appService:AppService) {
        this.result = new DataResponse();

        this.appService.get('http://xxx/scripts/xxx.php')
            .then(response => this.setResponse(response.json() as DataResponse))
            .catch(this.appService.handleError);

        for(let entry of this.result.data){ 
            entry.id_gng = entry.id_gng + 1; 
        };
    }
}
```

Как корректно осуществить цикл по this.result ? Вариант с for пробовал, выдает ошибку и все. Понимаю, что вопрос новичка. Спасибо.